# Applying class conditionally in sass/React using ternary operator

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I am fairly new to sass and React. I did not find this exact question when searching. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I wrote a basic real-time app using React, socket io, node and sass. I am trying to note which users are online/offline. I would like to do this by showing a green or red circle based on if they have active socket connections to a space. To accomplish this, I used a map and a ternary operator. This portions works without issue:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const members = this.props.users.map((user, i) => {
       console.log(user);

        return <li key={i} className={"member-info " + (user.active ? 
'online' : 'offline')}>                   
                    <h2>{user.username}<div className="circle"></div></h2>
                    <h4>Joined: {moment(user.joined).format("MMM Do YY")}</h4>               
                </li>
    })
```

The online users have the online class applied and the offline users have the offline class applied. I would like to use this value to determine the fill of the circle (className = circle) in the list below. I have tried several variations and have yet to get it working. So, if the user is online I would like the circle to have a background color of green and if offline, red. Here is my sass code for this portion. Members is the ul and member-info is the li. Any suggestions on how to accomplish the color variation above would be appreciated:

```
.members{
                border: 1px solid gray;
                background-color: royalblue;
                color: white;
                max-height: 45%;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                .member-info{
                    border: 1px solid gray;
                    padding: 10px;
                    a{
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: white;
                          a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
                          a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
                          a:focus { text-decoration: none; }
                          a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.users.map((user, i) => {
        return (
          <li
            key={i}
            // You might not need className on the <li>
          >
            <h2>
              {user.username}
              <div
                className={`circle ${
                  user.active ? "circle--online" : "circle--offline"
                }`}
              />
            </h2>
            <h4>Joined: {moment(user.joined).format("MMM Do YY")}</h4>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

And then your SASS:

```css
.circle {
  &--online {
    color: green;
  }
  &--offline {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

---

There's a few things I recommend.

Consider having a "default" state for your components, and then conditionally applying a modifier. Rather than...

```
"member-info " + (user.active ? "online" : "offline")
```

...try treating "offline" as your default state, and then conditionally adding "online" as your only modifier.

There's a very lightweight package (with zero dependencies) called [**classnames**](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames). It allows you to build conditional class strings more easily:

```js
import classNames from "classnames";

const classes = classNames("member-info", {
  "member-info--online": true  // <-- String: Boolean
}); // => "member-info member-info--online"
```

By only having a default state and a modified state, I can remove half of that SASS above. Assume "circle" by itself means offline, and "circle--online" means online:

```css
.circle {
  color: red;

  &--online {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

This naming convention, with the double-dashes, is called [**BEM**](http://getbem.com/naming/), and it lends itself pretty well to SASS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this syntax used before:

```
<li key={i} className={`member-info  ${user.active ? "online" : "offline"} `}>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The ternary operator and map work OK. I am trying to structure the sass code such that I can apply a background color based on if the li item has the online or offline class applied.